# JMeter returns wsdl as a response

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, jmeter, web-testing

Im trying to do simple web service test using `JMeter`. I'm using `SOAP/XML-RPC Request` with simpliest configuration

```
URL = https://...address here..?wsdl
SOAP action and Use KeepAlive stay unchecked
XML request is loaded from file, correctly
```

What is more i have added `View Result Tree` to see results. 
Thats all.

Problem is i'm still getting whole wsdl file as a response (i have expected a normal soap response for my xml soap requst).

I have tested in SOAPui this request and url - everythink working fine. Do i need do add smth more? maybe this is problem with `https` protocol?

What is more i have tried `WebService (SOAP) Request (DEPRECATED)` however im getting exception becouse of using `https` while i want to use `load WSDL`.

Any ideas to solve my problem?

Here is a request from `View Result Tree`

```
 POST https://...address here..?wsdl

 POST data:
 Filename: D:\install\apache-jmeter-2.11\TEST\request.xml
 <actual file content, not shown here>

 [no cookies]

 Request Headers:
 Content-Type: text/xml
 Connection: close
 User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
 Host: hostname
 Content-Length: 1826
```

EDIT: i solved this problem by doing configuration like this:

```
ULR = https://..address here.. (NO WSDL)
SOAP action specified (url from wsdl)
KeepAlive checked
XML pasted in textbox section
```

However when i load xml from file - test fails with message `couldnt parse stream`. The same message pasted into textbox section - works perfectly. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration:

- URL : scheme://..address here.. (NO WSDL)
- SOAP action specified (url from wsdl)
- KeepAlive checked
- path to XML file pasted into right section

File encoding:

- XML was not loading as i expected because of encoding. 
  I had set UTF-8 with BOM encoding while my service expected UTF-8 without BOM.